# How do i get local area using pincode or area name using HERE API?

Tags: here-api

How can we fetch local areas under a certain pincode/zipcode from HERE API, i can pass the pincode/area name, city and country to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Places Search API helps to locate near by area based upon the area name that can be specified in q parameter

> https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}&at=52.531,13.3843&q=Brandenburg+Gate &pretty Copy

Refer below documentation for detailed reference

> developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/quick-start-find-text-string.html

With postal code, Geocoder API fetches the area around the code. please refer documentations :

> developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode-postal-shape